# RTF to HTML via RichTextBox, how to set correct font-sizes?

Tags: c#, wpf, rtf

I have an `RTF` format text, received from a `UWP RichEditBox` by calling `Editor.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out string rtf);`. I need to convert it to an html, but the best solution what I found is the `MarkupConverter`. Anyway, this uses a `WPF RichTextBox`, which loads the RTF formatted text, then gets from there as an XAML, and then converts it to HTML.

The problem is that if I set a bigger font size, in RTF displays as `\fs44`, and when it converts to XAML, it is shown the following way: `FontSize="34.666666666666664"`. I would like to see `FontSize="34pt"` (or 35, doesn't matter).

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302188/6607702) why is this happening, but is there a way to tell the RichTextBox to round it and put that *pt* text?

I would be also thankful if you can suggest a better way to convert RTF to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by searching and replacing the font sizes in the html with a regexp:

```
public static string ConvertFloatingFontSize(string html) {
    var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"font-size:([0-9]+.?[0-9]*);");
    if (matches.Count > 0) {
        foreach (Match match in matches) {
            var fontSize = match.Value;
            if (html.IndexOf(fontSize) >= 0 && match.Groups.Count > 1) {
                double.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out double result);
                if (result > 0) {
                    int sizeAsInt = (int)result;
                    html = html.Replace(fontSize, $"font-size:{sizeAsInt}px;");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```